# I can't deploy my function on firebse, app(us-central1) fail

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

```
Function URL (app(us-central1)): https://us-central1-yisus-portfolio.cloudfunctions.net/app

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        app(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:app"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Is a server create on express that sends the HTML JS and CSS, but uses server-side rendering, when I deploy another app that ends to execute before, it works.
The documentation says that the function can't execute more than the 60s, and in the logs of the functions says that takes 13000 (millisecond I guess), but I am not sure if is that or if it is a mistake that I did.

BUT
When I run `firebase --serve --only functions, hosting`
**IT WORK**, but when I deploy not

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [ {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      } ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

**firebase.json**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { app } = require("./lib/server")
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**function index**

Comment: Please try running the deploy command with --debug flag (`firebase deploy --only "functions:app" --debug`) and see if there are any error logs you can pick out from it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) has this banner at the top right now:

> Cloud Functions deployment failures in us-central1 and europe-west1

So I assume that is also the cause of the error message you are seeing. I recommend checking the status page for updates.